# Check when the Table Database is insert a new row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-ajax

I'm a very new to AJAX

I have a table in a SQL Server database:

```
COMMENT(id, content, user, time);
```

I'm programming a Forum ASP.

in `showcomment.aspx,` I use a repeater control to display all comment of each topic.

I also use

- a `Timer` control to auto update `UpdatePanel` in to check the change of the `COMMENT` Table (inserted a new row or not), if it has a change--> update the Update Panel below.
- an `UpdatePanel` to update the new comment

Now I want to have a `PageMethod` or `Script` or something... to check when the COMMENT table has a change.

I need some solution or some advice about the "`check the table change method`".

Help!!!

UPDATE:

The function add a new row to table is in `addcomment.aspx` page, it's not in the same page with `showcomment.aspx` page. So I cant use a button with `Button_Click Event` to update the change after I click.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check when the table is inserted a new row and then auto update Repeater using UpdatePane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023048/how-to-check-when-the-table-is-inserted-a-new-row-and-then-auto-update-repeater)

Comment: sorry but you even dont understand what is my problem, so dont mind if I describe my problem in another way

Comment: You don't saw how the subjects are handled exactly.If you have a field on the table for when the record was inserted, you could see if the most recent record inserted on the same subject is newer than whatever the most recent displayed commend was. Alternatively, if you create a trigger to update an audit table with info on the record (subject, id, date inserted) could be checked to see if it's newer than the current most recent comment.